# Protobuf build fail in Yocto

Tags: protocol-buffers, yocto

I'm using bitbake 1.32.0, Yocto 2.2.2 (Poky) trying to add protobuf-c to my build.  I keep getting a build failure on protobuf_2.6.1 (protobuf-c depends on protobuf).

I can manually download the Protobuf source code and cross-compile it without any problems.  But for some reason Yocto can't build it.

During the Yocto build process, libprotobuf-lite.so links okay, but libprotobuf.so fails linking due to these errors:

```
| /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS): In function `__libc_csu_init':
| /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/csu/elf-init.c:87: undefined reference to `__init_array_end'
| /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/csu/elf-init.c:87: undefined reference to `__init_array_start'
| /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0/ld: .libs/libprotobuf.so.9.0.1: hidden symbol `__init_array_end' isn't defined
| /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0/ld: final link failed: Bad value
```

I have tried looking through the .o files that are part of libprotobuf.so but are not included in libprotobuf-lite.so, to see if anything directly references the missing symbols, but I haven't found anything useful yet.

For a while I thought the culprit was -nostdlib.  But then I saw libprotobuf-lite compiles just fine with that flag, and the -lc and -lgcc flags are included in the link command.

The recipe is a very straightforward autotools setup.

```
SUMMARY = "Protocol Buffers - structured data serialisation mechanism"
DESCRIPTION = "Protocol Buffers are a way of encoding structured data in an \
efficient yet extensible format. Google uses Protocol Buffers for almost \
all of its internal RPC protocols and file formats."
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/google/protobuf"
SECTION = "console/tools"
LICENSE = "BSD-3-Clause"

PACKAGE_BEFORE_PN = "${PN}-compiler"

DEPENDS = "zlib"
RDEPENDS_${PN}-compiler = "${PN}"
RDEPENDS_${PN}-dev += "${PN}-compiler"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = 
    "file://LICENSE;md5=af6809583bfde9a31595a58bb4a24514"

SRCREV = "bba83652e1be610bdb7ee1566ad18346d98b843c"

PV = "2.6.1+git${SRCPV}"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/google/protobuf.git"

EXTRA_OECONF += " --with-protoc=echo"

inherit autotools

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

FILES_${PN}-compiler = "${bindir} ${libdir}/libprotoc${SOLIBS}"

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

Here is the more complete error statement:

```
| arm-agl-linux-gnueabi-libtool: link: arm-agl-linux-gnueabi-g++  -march=armv7-a -marm -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=softfp -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4  -fPIC -DPIC -shared -nostdlib /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/usr/lib/Scrt1.o /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/usr/lib/crti.o /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/usr/lib/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0/crtbeginS.o  google/protobuf/stubs/.libs/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.o google/protobuf/stubs/.libs/atomicops_internals_x86_msvc.o google/protobuf/stubs/.libs/common.o google/protobuf/stubs/.libs/once.o google/protobuf/stubs/.libs/stringprintf.o google/protobuf/.libs/extension_set.o google/protobuf/.libs/generated_message_util.o google/protobuf/.libs/message_lite.o google/protobuf/.libs/repeated_field.o google/protobuf/.libs/wire_format_lite.o google/protobuf/io/.libs/coded_stream.o google/protobuf/io/.libs/zero_copy_stream.o google/protobuf/io/.libs/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.o google/protobuf/stubs/.libs/strutil.o google/protobuf/stubs/.libs/substitute.o google/protobuf/stubs/.libs/structurally_valid.o google/protobuf/.libs/descriptor.o google/protobuf/.libs/descriptor.pb.o google/protobuf/.libs/descriptor_database.o google/protobuf/.libs/dynamic_message.o google/protobuf/.libs/extension_set_heavy.o google/protobuf/.libs/generated_message_reflection.o google/protobuf/.libs/message.o google/protobuf/.libs/reflection_ops.o google/protobuf/.libs/service.o google/protobuf/.libs/text_format.o google/protobuf/.libs/unknown_field_set.o google/protobuf/.libs/wire_format.o google/protobuf/io/.libs/gzip_stream.o google/protobuf/io/.libs/printer.o google/protobuf/io/.libs/strtod.o google/protobuf/io/.libs/tokenizer.o google/protobuf/io/.libs/zero_copy_stream_impl.o google/protobuf/compiler/.libs/importer.o google/protobuf/compiler/.libs/parser.o   -lpthread -lz -L/home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0 -L/home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/lib -L/home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/usr/lib/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0 -L/home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/usr/lib /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/usr/lib/libstdc++.so -lm /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/usr/lib/libssp_nonshared.a -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/usr/lib/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0/crtendS.o /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/usr/lib/crtn.o  -march=armv7-a -marm -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4 -pthread -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-z -Wl,relro -Wl,-z -Wl,now   -pthread -Wl,-soname -Wl,libprotobuf.so.9 -o .libs/libprotobuf.so.9.0.1
| arm-agl-linux-gnueabi-libtool: link: arm-agl-linux-gnueabi-g++  -march=armv7-a -marm -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=softfp -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4  -fPIC -DPIC -shared -nostdlib /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/usr/lib/Scrt1.o /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/usr/lib/crti.o /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/usr/lib/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0/crtbeginS.o  google/protobuf/stubs/.libs/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.o google/protobuf/stubs/.libs/atomicops_internals_x86_msvc.o google/protobuf/stubs/.libs/common.o google/protobuf/stubs/.libs/once.o google/protobuf/stubs/.libs/stringprintf.o google/protobuf/.libs/extension_set.o google/protobuf/.libs/generated_message_util.o google/protobuf/.libs/message_lite.o google/protobuf/.libs/repeated_field.o google/protobuf/.libs/wire_format_lite.o google/protobuf/io/.libs/coded_stream.o google/protobuf/io/.libs/zero_copy_stream.o google/protobuf/io/.libs/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.o   -lpthread -lz -L/home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0 -L/home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/lib -L/home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/usr/lib/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0 -L/home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/usr/lib /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/usr/lib/libstdc++.so -lm /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/usr/lib/libssp_nonshared.a -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/usr/lib/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0/crtendS.o /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/usr/lib/crtn.o  -march=armv7-a -marm -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4 -pthread -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-z -Wl,relro -Wl,-z -Wl,now   -pthread -Wl,-soname -Wl,libprotobuf-lite.so.9 -o .libs/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS): In function `__libc_csu_init':
| /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/csu/elf-init.c:87: undefined reference to `__init_array_end'
| /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/csu/elf-init.c:87: undefined reference to `__init_array_start'
| /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0/ld: .libs/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1: hidden symbol `__init_array_end' isn't defined
| /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0/ld: final link failed: Bad value
| collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
| make[3]: *** [libprotobuf-lite.la] Error 1
| make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
| /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6dlleargen4/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS): In function `__libc_csu_init':
| /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/csu/elf-init.c:87: undefined reference to `__init_array_end'
| /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/csu/elf-init.c:87: undefined reference to `__init_array_start'
| /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0/ld: .libs/libprotobuf.so.9.0.1: hidden symbol `__init_array_end' isn't defined
| /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-agl-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0/ld: final link failed: Bad value
| collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
| make[3]: *** [libprotobuf.la] Error 1
| make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/work/cortexa9-neon-agl-linux-gnueabi/protobuf/2.6.1+gitAUTOINC+bba83652e1-r0/build/src'
| make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
| make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/work/cortexa9-neon-agl-linux-gnueabi/protobuf/2.6.1+gitAUTOINC+bba83652e1-r0/build/src'
| make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
| make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/work/cortexa9-neon-agl-linux-gnueabi/protobuf/2.6.1+gitAUTOINC+bba83652e1-r0/build'
| make: *** [all] Error 2
| WARNING: /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/work/cortexa9-neon-agl-linux-gnueabi/protobuf/2.6.1+gitAUTOINC+bba83652e1-r0/temp/run.do_compile.121250:1 exit 1 from 'exit 1'
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/cjholmes/gen4/build/tmp/work/cortexa9-neon-agl-linux-gnueabi/protobuf/2.6.1+gitAUTOINC+bba83652e1-r0/temp/log.do_compile.121250)
```

I could really use some pointers on what to look at next.  This has eaten a lot of hours already.

Comment: I have no specific experience with this, but it seems likely that protobuf-c depends on protobuf only for the machine where you run the generator (`protoc`). So if you are not planning to compile files on the target, you only need protobuf for the build machine.

Comment: This is not the problem with protobuf itself. Seems to be some trouble with toolchain. Linking order needs to be checked as the failure is in non-shared part of libc. But I can build myself in sumo branch of meta-oe without any issues (using poky build toolchain).